# Concurrent processing of messages (Python)

Tags: python, multithreading, concurrency

I have the following scenario:

There is one thread that manages long-polling HTTP connection (non-stop) from an API. When a new message arrives, it must be processed within the special `process()` method.

I just want to design it in a way that incoming messages will be processed concurrently, but there is another important point: in the end of each processing an answer should be passed to the outcoming queue, which is organized in a separated thread. From there the answers will be sent via HTTP.

Here is a scheme:
[image]

Let's consider that it can be 30-50 messages in a second, and procces method will work from 1 up to 10 seconds.

The question is: what library or framework can I use to implement this architecture?

As far as I have researched, Python Tornado have good benchmarks, but here I do not need a web framework, just a tool that can provide a concurrent running of message processors.

Answer (score 0):

Your message rate is pretty low. So you may freely use "standard" tools like `RabbitMQ`/`Redis`, `Celery` ("Celery Project") and `asyncio`.

`RabbitMQ`/`Redis` with `Celery` - are great tools to implement queues and manage your tasks and processes.

`Asyncio` is faster than Tornado but it doesn't matter for your task. What is more important is that asyncio gives you all the benefits of modern `async/await` coroutine technique.